# Python - Re-run subprocess call when it fails

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a script that calls a subprocess (speedtest-cli).

The script seems to randomly fail with the following error message:-

```
ERROR: timed out
ERROR: 'speedtest-cli --share' failed (exit code 1).
Retrieving speedtest.net configuration... Cannot retrieve speedtest configuration
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/steve/speedtest_dev.py", line 80, in <module>
    data[1] = data[1].strip("'") ##Finish date and time
IndexError: list index out of range
```

As far as I can tell it looks like there are two errors in here:-

a) Speedtest-cli fails by timing out

```
ERROR: timed out
ERROR: 'speedtest-cli --share' failed (exit code 1).
```

and

b) The data strip then fails as one would expect because there is no data.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/steve/speedtest_dev.py", line 80, in <module>
    data[1] = data[1].strip("'") ##Finish date and time
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I would like to catch the 1st error if possible and re-run the subprocess after an interval (60 seconds?).

I have tried creating a function:-

```
def run_speedtest():
  outfile = open(dataFile, "w+")
  subprocess.call(["/home/steve/speedtest-cli-extras/speedtest-csv", "--share"], stdout=outfile)
  outfile.close()
```

and then using a try statement like:-

```
try:
  run_speedtest()
except:
  print("1st attempt failed") #for testing only
  time.sleep(60)
  run_speedtest()
```

For some reason I only manage to run the first part of this and when that errors out the except statement doesn't seem to run.  The script then does this:-

```
#Separate Values from csv string
with open(dataFile, "r+") as f:
  data = f.read()
  data = data.strip()
  data = data.replace("\t","|")
  f.seek(0)
  f.write(data)
  f.truncate
f.close()

#Open file and  process
with open(dataFile, "r") as g:
  data = g.read()
  data = data.split("|")
```

writes to a database and sends an email when the one of the parameters is less than a defined value.

It all works fine unless the initial run_speedtest() fails.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check out the [retry](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/retry/) package. It might help you here.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after upgraded the recent python version and the solution can be:

export PYTHONHTTPSVERIFY=0

python your_script

It works for me though.